# What is the datetime format used by Sitecore's Date / DateTime field types and how can I generate this from a regular DateTime object

Tags: sitecore-client, content-management

When I turned on "Raw values" in Sitecore to examine a Date (or DateTime) field, I see a string in the form

```
20170310T130700Z
```

Looking at the regular .Net DateTime type, I don't see a standard format option which reproduces this format. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

What is an easy way to generate this format from a regular DateTime object and what is the *name* of this format used by Sitecore?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Scroll to the bottom for the updated answer*

---

This format (with `T` in the middle and ending with `Z`) is called by Sitecore `ShortIsoDateTime`. I don't know if that is official name of it or not.

You can get it using `Sitecore.DateUtil.GetShortIsoDateTime(dateTime)` method.

There are more formats which are used by Sitecore.

`Sitecore.DateUtil` class is a really good place to learn more about them.

And there is a guide on Sitecore Docs: [Date/time best practices](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices)

---

**EDIT:**

`Z` character is added only if

```
if (datetime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
    str += "Z";
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

Just run a test:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string string1 = Sitecore.DateUtil.GetShortIsoDateTime(dateTime);
// string1 is 20170310155908

dateTime = Sitecore.Common.DateTimeExtensions.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string string2 = Sitecore.DateUtil.GetShortIsoDateTime(dateTime);
// string2 is 20170310155908Z
```

---

**EDIT 3:**

You are right. I was wrong since the beginning. The correct answer is: **This format is called by Sitecore `IsoDate`**:

```
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    string dateTimeString1 = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(dateTime);
    // dateTimeString1 == "20170310T162500"

    dateTime = Sitecore.Common.DateTimeExtensions.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    string dateTimeString2 = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(dateTime);
    // dateTimeString2 == "20170310T162500Z"
```

Comment: That method actually returns in `yyyyMMddhhmmss` format for me (without the T and the Z)

Comment: OK I'm confused now. In linqpad it returns the `yyyyMMddhhmmssZ` format whereas in a unit test I get `yyyyMMddhhmmss`...

Comment: I think it depends on whether `yourDateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, `DateTimeKind.Utc` or `DateTimeKind.Local`.

Comment: Answer edited. "Z" is added only for `DateTimeKind.Utc` dates

Comment: Interesting point about the DateTimeKind, however irrespective of Kind it does not output the date with a `Z` after the date part.

Comment: @MatthewDresser did a quick test for you. Before specifying DateTimeKind there is no `Z`, after specifying, there is `Z`.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say `T` not `Z`. I found that it outputs with the Z at the end, but not the T in the middle.

Comment: @MatthewDresser another answer edit above ;) You are right, I was wrong. Answer updated.

Comment: The correct date format is ISO 8601 btw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0):

From a different side (.net / c#), you can always use custom formatter to format the date into any desired format.

For example, to convert the current datetime to the format that Sitecore uses, you could do the folllowing in c#:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"));
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

More on this can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx